# How to avoid bad records in Hadoop PIG and Hive?

Tags: hadoop, hive, apache-pig

Hi I am new in Hadoop i found that badrecords for any input format can be skipped in Java map reduce using SkipBadRecord class,so i just want to know how it possible in both Pig and Hive?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Bad Record Handling in Hive**

To filter bad records in hive, you can enable skip mode in query. Hive configuration for skip mode is:

```
SET mapred.skip.mode.enabled = true;
```

You need to set above command before your hive query.
You can also limit the configuration by providing following parameters:

```
SET mapred.map.max.attempts = 100; 
SET mapred.reduce.max.attempts = 100;
SET mapred.skip.map.max.skip.records = 30000;
SET mapred.skip.attempts.to.start.skipping = 1
```

More detail about this is available in this [link](http://frankenbyte.tumblr.com/post/31715142041/resilient-hive-queries)

**Bad Record Handling in Pig**

Pig is itself designed to handle bad records.
When processing gigabytes or terabytes of data, the odds are overwhelming that at least one row is corrupt or will cause an unexpected result. An example is division by zero, even though no records were supposed to have a zero in the denominator. Causing an entire job to fail over one bad record is not good. To avoid these failures, Pig inserts a null, issues a warning, and continues processing. This way, the job still finishes. Warnings are aggregated and reported as a count at the end. You should check the warnings to be sure that the failure of a few records is acceptable in your job. If you need to know more details about the warnings, you can turn off the aggregation by passing -w on the command line.

Please see the [this](http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1234000001811/ch08.html#data_layout) useful link related to pig

Comment: still i am getting an issue while inserting data from one hive table top another table. i am trying to copy data (more then 300 million rows) from hive table to Elasticsearch using this query:- insert overwrite table TableNameES select * from HiveTableName; & after inserting some of rows i am getting this exception. i know this is because of different data type of mapping in ES ... i want to skip inserting those row which one giving error not only this exception may be other exception.

Answer (score 1):

In hive you can achieve by leveraging a optimal value for this property

set mapreduce.map.skip.maxrecords=??

Comment: Thanks for this property name. Seems like `mapred.skip.map.max.skip.records` is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

`mapreduce.reduce.maxattempts` has been replaced by `mapred.reduce.max.attempts` and defaults to 4, so should not be set to 100 which seems to high.

`mapred.map.max.attempts` has been replaced by `mapreduce.map.maxattempts` and defaults to 4, so should not be set to 100 which seems to high.

`mapred.skip.attempts.to.start.skipping` has been replaced by `mapreduce.task.skip.start.attempts` and defaults to 2, which seems good enough.

`mapred.skip.map.max.skip.records` has been replaced by `mapreduce.map.skip.maxrecords`.

`mapred.skip.mode.enabled` does not seem to be available anymore, so might not need to be set.

So, the only setting that can help is something like below:

`SET mapreduce.map.skip.maxrecords = 30000;`